# Insert value in existing key name in laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

```
public function store($request)
    {
        return DB::table('website_setup')->select('header_logo')->insertGetId([
            'value' => $request->header_logo   
        ] 
        );   
    }
```

table

```
 Schema::create('website_setup', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->string('key');
                $table->longText('value')->nullable();
                $table->timestamps();
            });
```

And some keys are already created in database table

Comment: Do you mean to say update value for existing key?

Comment: yes. there is null value at first

Comment: ok, I understand and I think you're new to laravel so would suggest to check how Laravel eloquent model works and the `updateOrCreate` method.

Comment: try this 
model::where('key', 'header_logo')->update(['value' => $request->header_logo])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`upsert()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#upserts) method to insert new records and to update existing records with new values that you specify.

```
public function store($request)
{
        return DB::table('website_setup')->upsert([
            'value' => $request->header_logo   
        ]);   
}
```

Or use [`update()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#update-statements). Similar to the insert method, the update method accepts an array of columns and values that indicate the columns to be updated.

```
public function store($request, $id)
{
    return DB::table('website_setup')
              ->where('id', $id)
              ->update([
                'value' => $request->header_logo   
              ]);   
}
```